# Establish a connection between Azure CosmosDB SQL API and Google Bigquery

Tags: apache-kafka, google-bigquery, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I'm using Azure CosmosDB SQL API and I'm looking a way to send data from CosmosDB to Google Big query. I'm
planning to use Kafka or Azure ADF for the same. I'm not sure this is correct approach/tools.

Is there any best practice or tool or connecter which I can use to send data from CosmosDB to Google Bigquery.

Comment: Hello @Surya Pratap ,If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Data Factory supports Azure Cosmos DB (SQL API) as source and sink, but doesn't support [Google Bigquery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-google-bigquery) as the sink.
[image]

It means that we can not copy the data from Cosmos DB(SQL API) to Google Bigquery.